# The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type InputStream error

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

I am trying to get linked list implementation of stack-pop algorithm. Here is the complete code. The code is actually from the course Algorithm, part 1 in Coursera.

```
public class LinkedStackOfString {
    private Node first = null;
    private class Node {
        String item;
        Node next; 
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void push(String item) {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
    }

    public String pop() {
        String item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        return item;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedStackOfString stack = new LinkedStackOfString();
        while (!System.in.isEmpty())
        {
            String s = System.in.readString();
            if (s.equals("-")) System.out.println(stack.pop());
            else stack.push(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I am putting the full error statement. I get an error message like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type InputStream
    The method readString() is undefined for the type InputStream

    at linkedList/linkedList.LinkedStackOfString.main(LinkedStackOfString.java:30)
```

Can anyone please explain, what is happening? I am new to Java

Comment: I would suggest learn java basics and object oriented design first and then dive into algorithms..

Comment: Plus I'd suggest using a smart Java IDE, it will help you very much in your learning process.

Comment: `System.in` is an `InputStream` which has no method `isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 5):

Edit; You're trying to get input from a Scanner object, thats why you're referencing System.in. You need to create a new Scanner object using System.in as the InputStream.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedStackOfString stack = new LinkedStackOfString();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String input = scanner.next();

            if (input.equals("-")) {
                String popped = stack.pop();

                System.out.println(String.format("Popped value is %s.", popped));
            } else {
                stack.push(input);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to read input commands from console. Plus, there is no such method `readString` on his `LinkedStackOfString`.

Comment: Yeah I think readString() is suppose to be the name of the node or stack.pop(). I would presume. That is very possible though! I'll edit this.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need a program which keeps on adding the elements to the stack. I would suggest to change `main()` method as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedStackOfString stack = new LinkedStackOfString();

    String line ;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while( (line=in.nextLine() )!= "N"){
      if (line.equals("-")){
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
      }
      else {
        stack.push(line);
      }
    }
  }
```

This essentially means that the user should keep on typing anything that she wants to be added to the stack and enter `-` when she wants to `pop` and print the top element. The User can enter `N` when she wants to end this

Comment: Good job man! Only thing I would note is the unnecessary creation of the local member line that is re-initialized every loop. Just create a local member within the scope of the while loop to ensure no unintended access beyond the scope that its needed.

Comment: Yeah, valid point @Jason. Although the line is created only ones but its visible outside the scope of its use

Comment: Yeah it's definitely intended to be used the way that you're using it but people can be unpredictable! I've definitely done it before, and will continue to, just worth pointing out :).